# Prove that $x \pmod n = 0$ if $x \pmod n = (k*x) \pmod n $ and $ k \ne n$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I need a quick formal proof for :

Prove that  $x  \pmod n = 0$ if $x \pmod n = (k*x) \pmod n $ and $ k  \ne n$

Thanks

Comment: what kind of rules can you use?

Comment: Hi, please write down what you have done and whichever methods you have learnt

Comment: Note: if you don't upvote any of the answers then the question (and answers) will eventually be automatically deleted by the software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correcting notation, your inference is: $\, x\equiv kx\,\Rightarrow\, x\equiv 0\,\pmod n$

Notice $\, x\equiv kx \iff (k\!-\!1)x\equiv 0\pmod n\iff n\mid (k\!-\!1)x\,$

But only when $\,n\,$ is coprime to $\,k\!-\!1\,$ does that generally imply that $\,n\mid x.$

For counterexamples choose any $\,x\neq 0,\,k \ne 0,2\,$ and $\,n = (k\!-\!1)x,\ $ so $\ n\mid(k\!-\!1)x,\, $ but $\ n=(k\!-\!1)x\mid x\iff k\!-\!1\mid 1\iff \, k = 2\,$ or $\,k = 0,\,$ contra hypothesis.

Answer (score 0):

It's false:
$2\pmod 6\equiv (4\cdot 2) \pmod 6$, yet $2\not\equiv 0\pmod6$.